# Is there a way to add an email address to multiple users' Outlook 2007/2010's Safe Sender List without user input?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

We are looking for a method of adding an email address to multiple users' Outlook 2007/2010 (we have a mixed environment) Safe Sender's list without the users having to do anything. Is there a Microsoft approved method of doing this? We have a software distribution tool that we can utilize to copy files, insert registry entries, run scripts, MSIs, EXEs, etc. to accomplish this; we are just missing the file/registry entry/script/MSI/EXE. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Also, we do not want to overwrite any existing entries that users may have already added to their Safe Sender List.

Comment: What type of mail server are you using?  Why would you need to do this in the clients?

Comment: @Zoredache We are using Exchange 2010. I was under the impression this was not something that can be controlled by Exchange and that it was a client setting. Is this not the case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to append? I don't think this is very easy to do ... I think [Outlook Profiler](http://goffconcepts.com/products/profiler/) has a hidden ini file option, **SafeSenders**, that can do this ...